# Opening link on an HTML page to a specific page of a PDF on an iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, pdf

I've been searching for the answer to this for the past two days but can't get it to work.

I'm working on a web app built in HTML that is optimized for the iPad. One of the pages has different links to different pages of a 50 page pdf. I used the link on Adobe's site http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html using sample.html#page=2 and that worked in desktop browsers on Windows, but not on the iPad. I've also tried creating destinations in the PDF and linking to them, but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only real requirement is that no additional software can be downloaded for viewing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the "=" sign.

So: `sample.html#page2`

That should work for iPad.

Comment: For future reference, we just tested this and it works on iPads with iOS6+

Comment: As of this date, removing the "=" still works on Safari iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Those links work only with desktop versions of Adobe products. It might be possible for Adobe to add support for them in Adobe Reader for iPad in the future.

Comment: This is not true anymore, It also works on mobile devices and non-adobe products, the only place that I've found it doesn't work is in iOS devices

Answer (score -1):

Just

```
filename.pdf#pagenumber
```

**ex**

`wwww.domain/pdffile`